# what and how about firestore document field updates in batch

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Documentation says that writing to firestore documents is limited to 1 second per document.

Updating different fields of the document fast enough could cause data loss if device A is updating field A and device B is updating field B in the same time ?

**Will a batch that updates multiple documents on one or many fields fields fail if one of the documents is busy ?**

Does a batch that update document fields fail if one of the documents is busy ?

**If the batch update is used offline, what happens if the one of the documents included in the batch is busy when the user gets back online ?**

**in this video
https://youtu.be/dOVSr0OsAoU?t=240
it is stated that hybrid state of the data is impossible when using batches but if a batch was run offline does it get passed as a batch to the server when the user gets back online ?**

#askfirebase

Answer (score 0):

> Updating different fields of the document fast enough could cause data loss if device A is updating field A and device B is updating field B in the same time ?

It doesn't matter which fields are being updated.  If you exceed the rate limits for updates on the document in any way, the updates might fail.

> Does a batch that update document fields fail if one of the documents is busy ?

If any part of a batch write fails, the entire batch fails.  There is never partial success for batch writes and transactions.

> If the batch update is used offline, what happens if the one of the documents included in the batch is busy ?

The limits only apply to documents written to the cloud-based service.  They don't apply to documents cached locally which the app is offline.

If the app is offline, then no documents are written to the cloud.  If no documents are written to the cloud, then no write limits can be exceeded.

Comment: While it's hard to write the issue, I am experiencing an issue where my Firestore batch writes (in chunks of 400) are experiencing some random, failures. My batch commit message shows successful, but the actual data says otherwise. Although I understand, batch writes are supposed to success or fail altogether, the behavior doesn't seem to be the case. I rectified the problem by running the same batch write twice, it's only 500 documents...

Comment: it could possibly be due to this error - 2023-08-03 00:17:45.791951+0900 xxxx[24491:5752359] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (10d6551e8) Stream error: 'Internal: Received RST_STREAM with error code 2'